# 403 error when pushing to GitHub

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to push a new local branch (named "haystack") to my github repo with:

```
git push -u origin haystack
```

But I get the error:

> error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing https://github.com/Grails48/airbrake-grails.git/info/refs

This is the first time I've ever tried to push to this repo. I had a look in the "SSH Keys" section of my GitHub account and it says:

```
tony.drago@Office100 (b5:4d:e3:8f:26:76:cd:15:8b:c8:4c:f4:a7:fd:29:c3)
```

(that's not the real key value)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit your `.git/config` file so that the `url` is using either `ssh` or `git` protocol instead of `https`:

```
url = git@github.com:Grails48/airbrake-grails.git
```

Comment: should I replace 'git' above with my GitHub username?

Comment: Also, url = https://username:password@github.com/username/reponame should work. Note that :password part is not mandatory and not recommended, I just put it for reference.