# First time using GitHub, getting error 403 when I try 'git push'

Tags: git, github

I'm getting following error

```
remote: Permission to sokratus/xxxxxxxxxxxxx.git denied to user-name2.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/sokratus/xxxxxxxxxxxxx.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

The user-name2 belongs to one of my friend and I'm not sure why is it coming up on my computer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [403 error when pushing to GitHub](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308602/403-error-when-pushing-to-github)

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are trying to push to your friend's repository & you do not have permission to do so. This is probably what you did:

```
git clone https://github.com/sokratus/xxxxxxxxxxxxx.git/
## did something, git add or git commit....
git push
```

By default, git push pushes to the origin, you can check the repository to which origin points to by doing :

```
$ git remote -v
# which will give you something like this
origin https://github.com/sokratus/xxxxxxxxxxxxx.git/
```

If you want to push to the origin, then you need access to it. Or if you want to push it to your own github repository, then you need to create a new remote, like this:

```
$ git remote add my_origin <your github repository's url>
$ git push my_origin
```

Comment: No but the repo is mine. I created it with my own account. I didn't use git close at all.

Comment: Could you please paste the output of "git remote -v"?

Comment: Sokratus:SokratusPortfolio Sokratus$ git remote -v
origin https://github.com/sokratus/xxxxxxxxxxxxx.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/sokratus/xxxxxxxxxxxxx.git (push)

Comment: Then I think this is for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308602/403-error-when-pushing-to-github (as the other person commented above)

Comment: I can push it to my repo now, I added the 'user-name2' as a collaborator for that project. But all the pushes I'm doing are showing up as done by 'user-name2'.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! Apparently 'user-name2' of my friend was saved with password in my **Keychain** for **github.com**. I deleted those entries from Keychain and now the problem is solved! Thanks Upasana for all the help anyways. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your repo by pasting this on your terminal:

`$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:usename/repository_name.git`

This worked for me

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer could benefit from an explanation.