# how to send a pull request from android studio to github?

Tags: android, git, github

I shared a project on GitHub and my friend wanted to send me a pull request but whenever he sends a pull request he gets a error  saying "Push failed: unable to access URL LINK The requested URL returned error: 403" what is this error and how to give access ?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27887107/first-time-using-github-getting-error-403-when-i-try-git-push

Comment: have you searched anywhere ?

Comment: He needs to fork your repository and then send pull request or you need to add him as a collaborator on GitHub.

Comment: okay i think that would solve the problem . how do i add him as a collaborator?